# How to use Triggers as a Boundary?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code resets my camera(character) position if the user tries to exit the game boundaries by using a box collider and triggers. Would there be any way to stop the camera or bounce back the camera slightly when it enters/exits a trigger instead of resetting its position? Thank you

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BoundaryTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public float hoverForce = 12f;
    public Vector3 startPos;

    void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
     transform.position = startPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Would there be any way to stop the camera` - I might be missing something, but use the box collider as collision rather than a trigger?

Comment: All of the activity takes place inside the box collider - collision for the collider I believe takes place on the outside

Comment: If you mean you have 1 large box collider representing your game area, I think you'll need to change that so instead you have box colliders representing the outer walls.

Comment: I did that previously having four box colliders as the four walls but there was a lot of glitching and passing through at points? :/

Comment: Obviously when configured correctly, Unity collision does work without glitching - you'd need to post the details of how that was configured in another question so we could look at ironing out the glitches. I would certainly approach this problem like that though, rather than having a trigger you are kept inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Vector3 m_LastValidPosition = null;
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    m_LastValidPosition = transform.position;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    transform.position = m_LastValidPosition;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer - seems to be on the right tracks and I understand what your doing but sadly it does not work :/

Comment: mmm okay that is unfortunate. Let me make some other suggestions. How about for starters try to use a coroutine to set the last valid position every 1-2 seconds instead of using triggerStay. If that works we can improve the solution from there.